# Having issues with executing a Java classes file on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ant

I am following this tutorial: http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

But I have run into some problems.

Here is what I have done (the code is in ~/src/ant-demo/oata/):

```
javac -d ~/src/ant-demo/build/classes ~/src/ant-demo/oata/Hello*

java -cp ~/src/ant-demo/build/classes oata.HelloWorld
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oata/HelloWorld : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: oata.HelloWorld. Program will exit.
```

I am using Ubuntu with openjdk-7-jdk.

**UPDATE**

```
#java -version

java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.5) (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

#which java
/usr/bin/java
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're compiling with JDK7, but running with a previous version. Use `java -version` and `which java` to know which version of java you're actually using.

Comment: Are you talking about ant, also?

Comment: Err, no. My answer doesn't have the word "ant" in it. And in your question, you don't use ant at all. Your edits confirm what I say: java points to an older version of java. Change your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Of course not. You're already using usr/bin/java, and it points to Java 6. Include the JDK7's bin directory at the beginning of your path.

Comment: I did a find command and I found this: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java, and /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java So wich one do I use?

Comment: Or can I just cp the java file to the /usr/bin folder?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but I guess /usr/bin/java is just a symlink to some other physical file. I would change the target location of the symlink and make it point to your newest java file. You seem to have installed a JDK and a JRE. Choose the one you want, it shouldn't matter.